# Joomla Virtuemart category mobile layout

Tags: css, joomla, virtuemart

I am trying to resolve this problem for day and I found solution, but it is not as I imagine and what I would like to have, so I am reaching for greater and smarter minds here :)

I have web shop that is showing one product per row on mobile layout, like here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUlVL.png)

but I would like to see it two in a row. Now, this is the problem: in Configuration of Virtuemart, showing products per row is set to 3, because I would like to see 3 products per row on computer and desktop devices (also laptops and bigger tablets), so this is OK and everything works fine.

But on mobile devices, in template mobile.css this is set always to show 1 in a row.So I searched and I found code

```
.category-view .vm-col-3
```

that is set to `width: 100%`

When I insert this to 50% I get this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgVUz.png)

I insert `clear: none`and `float: left`nothing happened. So I figure it out I have to find some .row code, because I see that this is 3 products in a row like it is set in Configuration, only now it is smaller and sorted like this, but still not like I would like to have.

Then, I found line that sets the row:

```
.category-view .browse-view .row
```

and inserted this line:

```
clear: none;
float: left;
width: 50%;
```

With this, results are the closest, but still not what I need.
Always when it ends 9 products, next 3 are one under another (3 products) and then again starts with two in a row and repeats after 9 products.

You can see it here (with mobile phone): box2.appleoprema.com/index.php/iphone6-maskice-i-zastita

Can someone tell me please, how to fix this?
I have try many ways and codes to figure this out, and after 3 days I just don’t know what to do anymore.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there after having a look it seems that the structure of the container is like this

row
  col-1
  col-2
  col-3
row
  etc...

so adding `width: 50%;` to the row messes up everything because there are 3 products assigned to each row.

What you can do is either have `width: 33%` to `.product.vm-col.vm-col-3` for `media="(max-width: 640px)"` to display 3 products per row or leaving it as it is so that the column gets 100% of the width showing 1 product per row.

If you want to have 2 products per row for mobile display probably you should either check in the backend if there is such option or tweak the html of the component/module that you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is option for 2 products in a row in backend, but then on desktop is also show 2 rows. I need 3 rows on desktop and 2 rows on mobile. I thought that maybe I'll need to do something (edit) category products PHP file. If I leave 1 product, it will be difficult to scroll if I have 120 or 150 products.

I think only solution is 3 in a row :/

Comment: The only way you can accomplish this is by editing the php file of the component to override the options from the backend. This can be done by not putting the columns into rows and define the bootstrap class for each column like col-sm-6 col-md-4.